# Smell through Plastic

Tags: smell

Can smell go through plastic bags/gloves?

If it can, does the things in the bag ACTUALLY touch you?

Like cat poop, if it's in the bag my hands starts smelling but I don't feel it on my hands or see it on my hands. So is the cat poop on my hands or its just the smell of cat poop?

Answer (score -2):

Smell can go through, especially after prolonged time. The poop does not touch you, unless there are holes. The smell on your hands can be just imagination as you know what is inside.